# css and js show-hide function works on 2nd click only

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code:

```js
function UnhideFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("MyShow");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.myhide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="UnhideFunction()">SHOW ME</button>
<div id="MyShow" class="myhide">
  SOME TEXT
```

The problem is SOME TEXT shows only when I click SHOW ME twice.

How do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Your element doesn't have a style.display set on it to start with, so, while it starts as `display:none;` due to the `myhide` class, since `x.style.display` !="none", it is set to "none" on the first click.
However, using *both* a class and an inline style is messy. I would take a different approach, and simply toggle the "myhide" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is likely due to how the display property is being set and checked. When you initially hide the element by setting `display: none;`, the `x.style.display` property will be an `empty` string, not `"none"`.

This will fix the problem

```
<script>
function UnhideFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("MyShow");
  if (getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function UnhideFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("MyShow");
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(x); // Get computed style
if (computedStyle.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't be an inline `style.display`, you want to use `window.getComputedStyle(element)` if you're needing to parse the style out, but this won't be as performant as adding the original style inline (on the HTML style attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Some believe it you should toggle classes for a show/hide here is a data attribute alternative with perhaps less code.

```js
//get this out of the markup and in code.
document.querySelector(".toggle-button")
  .addEventListener('click', unhideFunction);

// use standard JavaScript name case
function unhideFunction(event) {
  const x = document.getElementById("MyShow");
  const currentVal = x.dataset.showme;
  x.dataset.showme = currentVal == "hide" ? "show" : "hide";
}
```

```css
.myhide[data-showme="hide"] {
  display: none;
}

.myhide[data-showme="show"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle-button">SHOW ME</button>
<div id="MyShow" class="myhide" data-showme="hide">
  SOME TEXT</div>
```

Overkill example to show how you can use that to add more functionality:

```js
//get this out of the markup and in code.
const t = document.querySelector(".toggle-button");
t.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
t.addEventListener("dblclick", handleDoubleClick, {
  once: true
});

//{
// const tgl = event.currentTarget;
// const t = tgl.dataset.toggletarget;
// const x = document.querySelector(t);
// const currentVal = x.dataset.showme;
//  x.dataset.showme = currentVal == "hide" ? "show" : "red";
//});

function handleDoubleClick(event) {
  console.log('should only see one time');
  const tgl = event.currentTarget;
  const t = tgl.dataset.toggletarget;
  const x = document.querySelector(t);
  x.append(' clickable now');
  x.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    handleClick(event);
  });

}

// use standard JavaScript name case
function handleClick(event) {
  const tgl = event.currentTarget;
  const t = tgl.dataset.toggletarget;
  const x = document.querySelector(t);
  const currentVal = x.dataset.showme;
  if (currentVal != "show" && currentVal != "hide") {
    //  console.log('its me', currentVal);
    x.dataset.showme = currentVal == "" ? "red" :
      currentVal == "red" ? "blue" :
      currentVal == "blue" ? "green" : "";
  } else {
    x.dataset.showme = currentVal == "show" || currentVal == "red" || currentVal == "blue" ? "hide" : "show";
  }
}
```

```css
.myhide[data-showme="hide"] {
  display: none;
}

.myhide[data-showme="show"] {
  display: block;
}

.other-target[data-showme="red"] {
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-color: #ff000033;
  content: "No red double";
}

.other-target[data-showme="blue"] {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background-color: #0000ff33;
  content: "No blue double";
}

.other-target[data-showme="green"]:after {
  border: solid 1px green;
  background-color: #00ff0033;
  content: " Green wins!";
}
```

```html
<span class='other-target' data-showme="">Try double click=></span><button class="toggle-button" data-toggletarget=".my-target">SHOW ME</button>
<div class="myhide my-target" data-showme="hide" data-toggletarget=".other-target">
  SOME TEXT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I done.

1. Passed inline style for more code readability.
2. Removed unclear and non-properly working if-else condition.
3. Now we keep show/hide toggle in `show` state which is changed on click.
4. I used a `tenary opearator` to change display either to block or none depending on condition.

```html
<script>
let show = false

function UnhideFunction() {
  show = !show;
  document.getElementById("MyShow").style.display = show ? "block": "none"
}

</script>

 <button onclick="UnhideFunction()">SHOW ME</button>
 <div id="MyShow" style="display:none;">
 SOME TEXT
 </div>
```

Hope it helps.